# How to add google adsense banner on a github page created with mkdocs-jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, github-pages, mkdocs

- I have generated the website using [mkdocs-jupyter](https://github.com/danielfrg/mkdocs-jupyter).

  - This allowed me to generate static website using a jupyter notebook files
  - You can see my [webpage](https://hellojinwoo.github.io/param_estimation/01.Maximum_Likelihood_Estimation/)
- I'd like to add a google adsense at the top of this page.
- I have asked GPT4 and its answer didn't work. The following is his answer:

```
1. Create a folder named templates in your MkDocs project, if it doesn't already exist.
2. Inside the templates folder, create a new file named custom_notebook.html.
3. In the custom_notebook.html file, extend the base.html template and override the content block with your AdSense code:

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <!-- Google AdSense Code -->
 ...(I put mt google adsense code here. Didn't include it here for a security reason)
  <!-- End Google AdSense Code -->

  <!-- Render the notebook content -->
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

4. Update the mkdocs.yml configuration file to use the custom template:
plugins:
  - search
  - mkdocs-jupyter:
      exclude: .ipynb_checkpoints
      template: templates/custom_notebook.html
```

- Can anyone tell me the code or the tutorial?

  - https://flipdazed.github.io/blog/website/google-adsense-and-google-analytics This article doesn't help.